# Force due to motion around Sun

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, orbital-motion, free-body-diagram

> Think of one person on earth named ***A*** . Ignoring Earth for a second, I can imagine him moving around the Sun due to which he should always feel some acceleration towards Sun (Centripetal Force) say F1. Now think of Earth. ***A*** also feels centripetal acceleration towards centre of Earth due to rotation, say F2. Well the forces F1 and F2 at some moment would be in the same direction i.e. towards sun and sometimes in the opposite direction. There is a clear variation in the net force on ***A***. Why doesn't he feel that? Why don't we feel the variation in force?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The centripetal acceleration in a circular motion with radius $R$ and angular velocity $\omega$ (angular velocity is velocity divided by circumference, or $2\pi/T$ with period of rotation $T$) is given by
$$a=\omega^2 R\,.$$
Can you find the accelerations due to the motion around the sun ($T=1\text{ year}$, $R\approx150\text{ million km}$) and the earth ($T=1\text{ day}$, $R\approx6800\text{ km}$)? How do they compare with gravitational acceleration due to the mass of the earth ($g\approx9.81\text{ m/s}^2$)?

Answer (score 1):

I would dispute your assertion (last line) that we don't *feel* these effects. If you mean why don't we feel it in our sense of balance or movement then the answer is as per @Toffomat - it's negligibly small. However, if you happen to be a long-range sharp-shooter or an artilleryman, you will certainly observe the effect that your rounds are landing off target due to some weird force that depends on latitude and direction of shot. This weird force is the Coriolis Force - well known to anyone involved in plotting motion over large distances and speeds.

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't he feel that? Why don't we feel the variation in force?

We most certainly do, [they're called "tides"](https://www.oc.nps.edu/nom/day1/partc.html).

The issue is that the force in question is very small compared to the force of the gravity of the Earth. So although it is having an effect on you, it's too small to notice, and too slow changing.

The force is so small that, acting across the distance of the entire planet, it can lift water a couple of feet. So you might imagine that the same force acting across the distance of your body is a *tiny* amount.

Tider are very cool. If you want to see how cool, go read *Neutron Star* by Niven, it will explain all of this and is entertaining as well.